# Change default font size while using fontspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontsize, fontspec

I'd like to set the main font size (i.e. all text which isn't a heading or something else with an explicit font size) to a particular font size, in this case, `9.5pt`.

I can't use the default package options. I also can't use `\fontsize{9.5pt}{9.5pt}\selectfont` at the start of my document because then latex (xelatex 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (MiKTeX 2.9)) selects some other font than the font set with `\setmainfont`.

What's a nice, simple way to set the default font size, analogous to the `\setmainfont` command from fontspec?

I have no version information about fontspec.

Comment: `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=0.95]{Some Nice Font}`

Comment: Please provide a bit more information about how the problem arises. Ideally, the information would come in the form of an MWE (minimum working example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Please also provide information about the version of XeLaTeX and `fontspec` that you use.

Comment: @egreg Scaling doesn't sound right, not least because the final size depends on whatever is set by the package.

Comment: @Mico I'm not sure what you want in my minimal working example. I know what an MWE is, but I don't see what you would get from it. All the information is already in this post.

Comment: Then build a package yourself, changing from `size10.clo`, to use what you need. But it's not at all clear what you want.

Comment: @egreg Surely you realise what an incredibly unhelpful response that is.

Comment: An MWE would provide further important information -- not contained in your posting -- such as real error and/or warning messages that could shed light on what's going on.

Comment: @Mico There are no error messages. The behaviour is as described. Not every question requires an MWE.

Comment: @Marcin You're saying that XeLaTeX selects a different font; this is not what one expects and XeLaTeX does normally; so a MWE *is* needed. However, my proposal *will* work, because when a 10pt font is requested, XeLaTeX will use it scaled, so you'll get 9.5pt.

Comment: It may be the case that not *every question* requires an MWE. Experience does show, though, that the odds that someone will come up with a diagnosis and, better still, a solution to the problem(s) you describe improve dramatically if an MWE is, in fact, provided.

Comment: @Mico If you don't like the way I've asked this question, feel free not to answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to do this (without, perhaps, using the KOMA packages), is to redefine `\normalsize`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
\@setfontsize\normalsize{9.5pt}{11.5pt}% Will look incredibly crabbed if line height is too small
\abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@%
\abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus2\p@%
\belowdisplayshortskip 5\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus3\p@%
\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip%
\let\@listi\@listI%
}
\normalsize  
\makeatother
```

Code adapted from: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/ChangeFontUsingLatex

Comment: It's disappointing to me that people downvote without explaining their downvotes.  Now I have no idea whether this is a useful answer or not without doing my own investigation.  I know that some people believe in downvoting answers by the person asking the question.  (I don't.) Perhaps that's the reason.

Comment: Hey, was looking to scale an entire document including math, and yours was the only answer which accomplished that! However, to get a consistent document for large sizes, you really have to redefine \small, \large, \huge etc., essentially redo from scratch what the .clo files do for standard document classes. Interesting that header comments in `size12.clo` mention classes.dtx with options `12pt`. So maybe the .clo files can actually be computed with the base size as a parameter, and one might even try to roll a package that does this for any size. It won't be perfect but sounds tempting.

Answer (score 29):

I can't see what's wrong with scaling the main font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=0.95]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\linespread{0.95833} % 11.5/12

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

With `\Large` you'll get 13.4 instead of 14pt; it doesn't seem a big difference (and I'd say it's even better). At `\Huge` the font will be 24pt instead of 25pt.

[image]

This can be supplemented by appropriate `\DeclareMathSizes` commands, where the last three arguments are scaled at 95%:

```
\DeclareMathSizes{5}{4.75}{4.75}{4.75}
\DeclareMathSizes{6}{5.7}{4.75}{4.75}
\DeclareMathSizes{7}{6.65}{4.75}{4.75}
\DeclareMathSizes{8}{7.6}{5.7}{4.75}
\DeclareMathSizes{9}{8.55}{5.7}{4.75}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{9.5}{6.65}{4.75}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{10.4}{7.6}{5.7}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{11.4}{7.6}{5.7}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{13.68}{9.5}{6.65}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xviipt}{16.42}{11.4}{9.5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xxpt}{19.7}{13.68}{11.4}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xxvpt}{23.64}{19.7}{16.42}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not scale math, which the `\normalsize` solution does.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Sorry, but scaling math was not required; redefining `\normalsize` is definitely not the way to go. There's the much safer `\DeclareMathSizes` command.

Comment: Yes, that definitely looks like dangerous tinkering and too low-level. But see my comment below for @Marcin's answer, is a package setting default document font size, including math, to an arbitrary integer parameter possible? Being stuck with standard 10, 11, 12pt while having all of the fontspec's modern might at your disposal is really silly.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov I added the suitable `\DeclareMathSizes` commands

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov A good solution is to load `unicode-math` and `\setmathfont` with `scale=MatchLowercase`.

Comment: The problem with scaling the main font is that some journals require exact font sizes of various pieces of text.  Is there a way to ensure that you're getting e.g., exactly 11.5pt size?

Comment: @JonathanW. If the font design size is 10pt and this matches the document class size option, `Scale=1.15` should do. If you use `11pt` as size option, `Scale=1.04545`.

Comment: @egreg, does Scale adjust all aspects of font size correctly?

Comment: @JonathanW. Yes, as far as I know.

Comment: @egreg, please see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315481/90570) in regards to the issue of using `Scale` to specify font size.

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford to use a different class, then the Koma-Script ones will give you a lot more flexibility in terms of size:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11.5pt]{scrartcl}
```

This has the added advantage that it applies to all fonts in the document (tt, etc), without requiring individual scaling.